# Land peeks thru on ground overlays

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I'm overlaying large maps on Google Earth, but parts of the underlying map peeks through the images:
[image: http://www.viseyes.org/Capture.JPG)]

I've tried all kinds of `setAltitudeMode()` and `setAltitude()` settings, but no joy.

Is this a known bug, or is there a work-around?

Thanks!

Bill

```
seg = ge.createGroundOverlay(m.mid);

latLonBox = ge.createLatLonBox('');
latLonBox.setBox(m.north, m.south, m.east, m.west, m.rotatio);
seg.setLatLonBox(latLonBox);    

icon = ge.createIcon('');
icon.setHref(m.url);

seg.setDrawOrder(-1);
seg.setIcon(icon);
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(seg);
```

Comment: To help debug, can you please provide which operating systems and versions of the plugin you see this issue on?  Additionally, if on Windows only, can you provide your video card and whether you're using OpenGL or DirectX?  Alos, do you notice this only in the plugin and not the desktop client?

Comment: I've seen it many Windows 7 systems. I use a RADEON 4350, but it also shows up on the built-in AMD Radeon chip. It does not show up in the Google Earth desktop app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings you want are `<altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>`

FYI - the only two allowed options are `clampToGround` and `absolute` (there are more options if using the `gx:altitudeMode`)

You should also have `<altitude>0</altitude>`

Judging by the image provided, you have set the mode to `absolute` with a non zero `altitude`

I would also avoid using a negative number for `drawOrder` - I am not sure they are valid?? besides, you want it on TOP of the GE imagery, so the drawOrder should be higher than it's (and I doubt it's drawOrder is -2 or lower)

Good Luck!

EDIT: After seeing example page in comments (which works for me) I think you should determine what version of the plug-in you have and maybe update it. Either that or update your video card drivers.

[This link](http://www.google.com/earth/explore/products/plugin.html) will tell you what version you have (it is listed under the GE window)

I am using 6.2.2.6613 but the latest is 7.x I believe. If you are under 6.x I would recommend an update

[This link](http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178389) has information on how to manually uninstall the GE plug-in, then simply visit your webpage to re-install it

Comment: I had tried these before:

  seg.setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_CLAMP_TO_GROUND);
  seg.setAltitude(0);

but I get the same bleed through. Any ohter thought>

Comment: Without an actual demo it is hard to guess further. Have you changed the 'TerrainExaggeration'? Did you try changing the 'drawOrder'?

Comment: Thanks for your help! The terainExaggeration is set to 1. I've tried a varierty of drawOrder values too. Here's a link to the app: http://www.viseyes.org/mapscholar

Comment: I've had a quick play with the webpage, pretty nice too so well done. It all seems to work fine for me, I am wondering what version of the plugin are you using? I'm going to edit answer to provide some links

Comment: Thanks. I could say the same about your great 3Dwhistler site as well. Its funny, it seems to only happen on Windows. My Mac  renders them fine. This is looking more like a Goog;le Earth bug!

Comment: I'm running Version 7.0.2.8415 and have the latest video drivers

Comment: Sorry Bill, I can not think of anything else.

Comment: We sent the link of this discussion to Google and they seemned to think it was a bug. Thanks so much for all your help here.