# Google Earth overlay disappearing

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I've created a simple triangular overlay using the Winforms GE API.  As I'm zooming in and out parts or all of the overlay will disappear.  The overlay is on the order of 80 miles in length.

The overlay is set to an altitude of 100 so I understand that when the overlay goes through a terrain feature it will disappear.  My concern is when it is completely visible and I zoom in it disappears completely or in part.  Since it is visible at a higher altitude shouldn't it also be visible at a lower altitude? (and I do realize that once I go 'below' the overlay it will disappear.  This is not my problem.)

Any ideas or thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a ground overlay should stay on top of the terrain. So when the terrain is higher than '100' the overlay should be 'wrapped' over top of it. I am not sure about the overlay 'disappearing' at various heights (POV)

Recently, there was [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562878/land-peeks-thru-on-ground-overlays) - and the OP ended up saying they had contacted Google and the consensus was it was some sort of bug.......